# Make python code for searching through dictionary more efficent (vigenere cipher)

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I'm writing some code to go through the vigenere cipher with different possibilities, and then making it only add the list to the possible options that result in a word when decrypted (that way I don't get thousands of print outs, I only get told with the most likely possibilities).

Here's the code so far

```
def vigenere(input):
    print("VIGENERE")
    key = ""
    keyList = []
    textList = []
    for word in englishDictionary:
        key = re.sub('[\W_]+', '', word)
        if key[:len(input)] not in keyList:
            while len(key) < len(input):
                key = key + key
            keyLetters = list(key.upper())
            keyNumbers = []

            for x in keyLetters:
                keyNumbers.append(alphaNum.get(x))
            vigenereOutput = ""

            for z in list(input):
                try:
                    keyNum = int(keyNumbers[0])
                except IndexError:
                    pass
                keyNum = keyNum - 1
                inbetween = int(alphaNum.get(z)) - keyNum
                del keyNumbers[0]

                if inbetween < 1:
                    inbetween = 26 + inbetween
                vigenereOutput = vigenereOutput +    numAlpha.get(str(inbetween))

            if vigenereOutput in englishDictionary:
                keyList.append(key[:len(input)])
                textList.append(vigenereOutput)
    if len(keyList) > 0:
        for keyEntry in len(keyList):
            print("Key:", keyList[keyEntry])
            print("Text:", textList[keyEntry])
    print()
```

The englishDictionary is a list of all the words in my dictionary text file (fairly big file, but using a small one would ruin the point of this decoder)

Right now however it takes over 20 minutes to go through the entire dictionary... how can I speed this process up?

Comment: I only skimmed the code, but have you considered using an _actual_ dictionary (i.e. the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) type) instead of two lists holding the keys and values, repectively?

Comment: What @tobias_k said, plus make functions that do one thing, plus profile and measure where time is spent, so you can focus on what takes time. There is probably also some preprocessing that could be done.

Comment: Also, do you check _each_ word in the `englishDictionary` to see whether it's in your input? How about instead splitting the input and checking whether it's in the `englishDictionary`? Seems more natural to me, and should be much faster, particularly if the `englishDictionary` is a `set`.

Comment: I'll look into that right now and update when I do that, thanks for the suggestions so far!

Comment: @tobias_k the input is supposed to be an encoded word (IE not a dictionary word) and the output should be the word decoded. I'm operating off of the assumption that the key and the output are dictionary words

Comment: It's difficult to understand the code in your question because it isn't indented properly and references a number of undefined global variable such as `englishDictionary` and `alphaNum`. You've sort of described the former, but not the latter. Precise definitions of both are probably needed to help you.

Comment: @martineau hey sorry about that, the code this is in is 300+ lines long so I only copied over part of it. alphaNum is a dictionary that converts letters to their numerical value (A to 1, Z to 26).

Comment: OK, that helps. Since your `englishDictionary` is a list instead of a Python dictionary (type `dict`), searching though it will be linear (i.e. dependent on its size O(n)). If you put the data in a Python dictionary (or even better a `set`) as others have already commented, searching though it would become a much more efficient O(1)). In either case you could check for membership in it with something like `if word in englishWords: ...` and it would be very fast.